# Error adding a child node

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, sprite-kit

I'm getting the following error trying to add enemy nodes to my scene. The error message is : `Attemped to add nil node to parent: <SKNode> name:'(null)' position:{0, 0} accumulatedFrame:{{inf, inf}, {inf, inf}}`

```
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff905a541c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8a101e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff905a52cc +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   SpriteKit                           0x00000001000cc754 -[SKNode addChild:] + 161
    4   InvadersMacTest                     0x0000000100011fe0 -[MapScene initWithSize:] + 3552
    5   InvadersMacTest                     0x00000001000042fb -[OpcionesMenu handleKeyEvent:keyDown:] + 875
    6   InvadersMacTest                     0x0000000100004514 -[OpcionesMenu keyUp:] + 100
    7   SpriteKit                           0x000000010008ded8 -[SKView keyUp:] + 67
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8ee90f71 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 3721
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8ee31ca2 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 3395
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ec81a29 -[NSApplication run] + 646
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ec6c803 NSApplicationMain + 940
    12  InvadersMacTest                     0x0000000100003902 main + 34
    13  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8d75a5fd start + 1
```

The code used to add the node is the following, i'm not doing something exceptional or tricky, just create a rectangle which simulate an enemy.

SKScene method

```
self.almacenEnemigos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:kNumEnemigos];

for(int i = 0; i < kNumEnemigos; i++)
{
     enemigo *nemesis = [[enemigo alloc] init];
     [nemesis pintarEnemigo:CGPointMake(200+5*i, 200+5*i)];
     [self.almacenEnemigos addObject:nemesis];
     [self.world addChild:nemesis->cobra];
}
```

And the method `pintarEnemigo` in enemigo class:

```
@interface enemigo()
    @property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *cobra;
@end

-(SKSpriteNode*)pintarEnemigo:(CGPoint) pos
{
    self.cobra = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[SKColor orangeColor]
                                                        size:CGSizeMake(80.0f, 60.0f)];
    self.cobra.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:25];
    self.cobra.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    self.cobra.position = CGPointMake(pos.x, pos.y);
    self.cobra.name = @"Pulpo";

    return self->cobra;
}
```

and enemigo.f file as demanded:

```
@interface enemigo : personaje
{
    @public
        SKSpriteNode *cobra;
}

-(id)init;
-(SKSpriteNode*)pintarEnemigo:(CGPoint) pos;

-(BOOL)enviarMensaje;
-(BOOL)mensajeRecibido;
```

Comment: Can you show us `enigmo.h`? I think you made a mistake there too.

Comment: header file enemigo added

Comment: Updated my answer, now that I've seen enigmo.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `self->cobra`? That's your bug. The value is `nil`. It's never set to the object you created a few lines earlier.

I'm pretty sure you meant to use `self.cobra`.

The `->` operator exists in Objective-C but should pretty much never be used, except maybe once or twice in ten years of programming. You should definitely never use it on `self`, although it is syntactically correct.

Your class has two instance variables, one is `cobra` and the other is `_cobra`. You're setting a value to `_cobra` and then returning the value of `cobra`.

`self.cobra` will return access `_cobra`, while `self->cobra` will access `cobra`.

In your *.h file, this line is incorrect:

```
 SKSpriteNode *cobra;
```

You have three options to fix it:

- change it to be named `_cobra`, which is the correct name for `@property cobra`;
- delete the line altogether, and then the compiler will created `_cobra` automatically for you.
- add an `@synthesize` rule to the enigmo.m file telling the compiler to use `cobra` instead of `_cobra` (lookup the documentation for `@synthesize` to learn how).

Once you've done that, you need to change the `return self->cobra` line to either:

- return self.cobra;
- return _cobra;
- return cobra;

Which one depends on what you do in the header file, but I suggest the first option, since that is the generally accepted best practice for obj-c programming.

Comment: You can use -> in Objective C as well. It is other way of referring to object members.

Comment: @ldindu I know you can use it, but you shouldn't. It exists for those rare occasions when it's needed, but this is not one of those occasions.

Comment: @JorgeVegaSánchez did you try any of Abhi's ways to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change:

```
@interface enemigo()
    @property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *cobra;
@end
```

to

```
@interface enemigo()
    @property (nonatomic,strong) SKSpriteNode *cobra;
@end
```